# Combining Two jQuery .val() Results Into Variable

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is fairly elementary; however, I just can't get it to work.  It's a two step process.  First, I want to combine the values of two dropboxes into a string.  Second step, I need to display any ID field found in a table row that matches that string.  Here are the two lines of code; however, something is not quite working out for me yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var $result = $('#provider').val() + $('#grade').val();
$('tr[id*=\"$result\"]').show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't combining the variables — the string concatenation should be just fine.

JavaScript doesn't perform variable replacement in strings, the way PHP does. Here's the fix:

```
var result = $('#provider').val() + $('#grade').val();
$('tr[id*="' + result + '"]').show();
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the quick response.  The provided code works perfectly!  Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('tr[id*="' + $result + '"]').show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response too, I went with the other poster for providing just the small bit of additional information which could potentially help someone else understand why exactly the code works.  Much appreciated!